# React too many rending with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, use-state

My Code :

```
import Item from './Item_att.js';
import axios from 'axios';

const Attraction_list = () => {
...
const [maindata, setMainData] = useState([]); //setData
const [postsPerPage] = useState(6);
...

let attList = async (areaCode, cityCode) => { //approach openAPI
    const url = `...`;
    try {
        const {data: res} = await axios.get(url)
        const list = res.response.body.items.item;

        console.log("rendering!")
        setMainData(list);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

...

attList(1, 1).then(data => {console.log("then");}) //make maindata
const currentPosts = (tmp) => {    //slice data
    return tmp.slice(indexOfFirst, indexOfLast);
}

...

return (
    <div>
        ...
        <Item rlist={currentPosts(maindata)} moveTo={moveTo} area={area} city={"강남"}></Item>
    </div>
);
};

export default Attraction_list;
```

Function `attList` brings data from openAPI.
Function `currentPosts` is executed when component `Item` is rendering, it returns a sliced list.

I think they executed only once,

Result :
Too much rerendering on this program. Function `attList` and function `currentPost` executed too many times. I don't know why.

Why rerendering so much?

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function attList inside a useEffect hook, else it will be called on each rerender of the component.

```
React.useEffect(()=>{

    attList(1, 1)

},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
setMainData(list);
```

inside your attList function, react will rerender your component as there is a state change. This will then run your attList function again which is what is causing the loop.

To prevent this behaviour you can use the useEffect react hook to call the attList function once on the first render and only on the first render.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

You have made an infinity loop because the `attList` will execute `setMainData`  which will then rerender the component again and therefor execute the `attList` again.

This is why you should use the `useEffect` hook, to make sure that the `attList` is only executed when you wan't it to. If you do as shown above, then it will only happen when the component is mounted.